# Can I Make A Receiver That Waits For A Long Press?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, long-press

I want to trigger an activity via long press on home screen.

Is this possible via broadcast receivers? Should I make a service?

Well let me be more specific. I have a tutorial that shows the actions (single tap, long press, on scroll etc) and on long press starts an activity that gets the GPS location. Now I want to do this when I long press the home screen. Is this possible? I have to say that I am new to Android development and I need to apologize if am not understanding something right away. Do you have any other suggestions on what I am trying to do?

Comment: No, Unless you are making your very own Launcher Application, this will not be possible.

Comment: Well let me be more specific. I have a tutorial that shows the actions(single tap, long press,on scroll etc) and on long press starts an activity that gets the gps location! Now i want to do this when i long press the home screen!Is this possible?I have to say that i am new to android development and i need to apologize if am not understanding something right away!Do you have any other suggestions on what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want to do this when i long press the home screen!Is this possible?

As @st0le indicated, no, unless you write your own home screen.